# Cannot delete files on AWS Lightsail via FileZilla/SFTP, permission denied

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

Want to delete wp-admin and wp-includes folders. I deleted most files. But cannot delete ALL files on AWS Lightsail via FileZilla/SFTP, permission denied.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

connect to your lightsail instance using ssh
and type this command,

```
sudo chown -R bitnami /opt/bitnami/apps
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).